# How do I just diplay field time only on edit mode for date column in Lightning Datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have this column for Start Time(type: date) which dipslays the time only as you can see in the image below. Here's the config for the column:

```
{
   label: 'Start Time', 
   fieldName: 'Start_Time__c',
   type: 'date',
   editable: true
}
```

[image]

But when I edit it, the date and time fields are showing.

[image]

I only want the time to show. How do I do that?